# Installing Matplotlib - errors importing numpy in test command

Tags: python, path

I'm having trouble getting matplotlib up and running.  I've downloaded it, but when I try to run the test command `python -c 'import matplotlib; print matplotlib.__version__, matplotlib.__file__'` I get the following errors

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 135, in <module>
    from matplotlib.rcsetup import (defaultParams,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/rcsetup.py", line 19, in <module>
    from matplotlib.colors import is_color_like
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/colors.py", line 52, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

I know I have numpy installed, as I've used numpy and can work with it.  `import numpy` in the python shell works just fine.

Maybe this is a PATH issue, but I'm not really sure.

Thanks

Comment: You probably have numpy installed into python 2.6

Comment: Sure, but how would you recommend I procede?  Uninstall 2.6 and numpy, then reinstall numpy on 2.7?  Install numpy on 2.6 and 2.7 (how?)  Somehow tell matlabplot to look at the correct place?

Comment: @tshauk: I would recommend that you try that. If that still doesn't work, then try using sys.path.append to manually append the numpy path to the PATH

Comment: Voted up because I was reading numpy as "numb-pee" and I was like, WTF is numb-pee?!

Comment: pip3 install --user numpy matplotlib